# Synchronize problems

Tags: java, synchronize

Basically, I need my program to pause while I'm waiting for input from a JTextField which is in the main JFrame, alongside all other elements so it is not a popup. However, the way I am doing it at the moment it pauses the whole program as I am using while(true), or something similar.

Here is how my GUI looks so you have a better idea of what I am talking about;

[image: img]

as you can see the program gets stuck when I enter the command `start` and press enter.

---

This is the way I initialize my synchronize:

```
    input = new JTextField();
    inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(input, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (waitingForInput) {
                synchronized (holder) {
                    holder.add(input.getText());
                    holder.notify();
                }
                waitingForInput = false;
            }

            JTextField sauce = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            appendCommand(sauce.getText());
            sauce.setText("");
        }
    });
```

and here is what happens when I call notify on the LinkedStack...

```
public String getInput(String s) {
    appendInput(s + ": ");
    input.requestFocus();

    synchronized (holder) {
        while (holder.isEmpty())
            //System.out.println("input inside 2"); //STOPS HERE
            try {
                holder.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("input inside 3");

        String nextString = holder.remove(0);

        System.out.println(nextString);
        return nextString;
    }

    /*Document document = getConsoleInput().getDocument();
    Element rootElem = document.getDefaultRootElement();
    int numLines = rootElem.getElementCount();
    Element lineElem = rootElem.getElement(numLines - 2);
    int lineStart = lineElem.getStartOffset();
    int lineEnd = lineElem.getEndOffset();
    try {
        System.out.println(document.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart));
        return document.getText(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "-1";
    } */           //another attempt I had
}
```

---

This is the hierarchy or chain of methods that get called, in order:

The start where I initialize the JTextField:

```
input = new JTextField();
    inputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(input, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (waitingForInput) {

                synchronized (holder) {
                    holder.add(input.getText());
                    holder.notify();
                }
                waitingForInput = false;
            }

            JTextField sauce = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            appendCommand(sauce.getText()); //<<<
            sauce.setText("");
        }
    });
```

AppendCommand(String s) method which is called inside the EDT

```
public void appendCommand(String s) {
    appendInput(s);
    if (!testIfValid(s)) return;
    handler = new CommandHandler(getCurrentInstance());
    switch (CommandList.valueOf(s.toUpperCase())) {
        case HELP:
            handler.help();
            break;
        case START:
            handler.start(currentLevelActive);  //<<<<<<<<<<<
            break;
        case STOP:

            break;
        case EXIT:

            break;
        //default:

    }
}
```

next :

```
  public void start(Level l) {
    level_instance = l;
    if (level_instance != null) {
        level_instance.start();
    } else {
        //CREATE new level
        int width = 0, height = 0;
        boolean go;

        console_instance.waitingForInput(true);
        console_instance.setInputMessage("Enter level width : ");
        InputThread widthThread = new InputThread("width", console_instance);

        while (!widthThread.done) {
        } ///STOPS HERE ETERNALY!!
        width = widthThread.getInputResult();

        ...
```

InputThread class:

```
class InputThread extends Thread {
Console console_instance;
String choice;
int inputResult;
boolean done;

public InputThread(String s, Console c) {
    console_instance = c;
    choice = s;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String s = "";
    console_instance.setWaitingForInput(true);
    do {
        s = console_instance.getInput("Enter " + choice + " of the level"); // <<<<<<<<<<
    } while (!isInt(s));
    inputResult = Integer.parseInt(s);
    done = true;
}

public int getInputResult() {
    return inputResult;
}

private boolean isInt(String s) {
    int i;
    boolean b;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        b = true;
        if (i < 0) {
            b = false;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
        b = false;
    }
    return b;
}
}
```

Console.getInput(String s) method:

```
public String getInput(String s) {
    appendInput(s + ": ");
    input.requestFocus();

    synchronized (holder) {
        while (holder.isEmpty())
            //System.out.println("input inside 2"); //STOPS HERE
            try {
                holder.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("input inside 3");

        String nextString = holder.remove(0);

        System.out.println(nextString);
        return nextString;
    }
}
```

and that's where it stops, in that loop. This however also stops the whole program.

For possible solutions I have tried to isolate portions of code inside Threads, however to no avail... If you could help me revamp this code so it functions correctly or give me another way to achieve this, that would be great.

---

EDIT:  as @markspace suggested, I tried to implement `SwingWorker`, firstly in the EDT thread, which did not work as the UI still got hung up, then in the `getInput(String s)` method. For the latter, this is what the code looked like:

```
public String getInput(String s) {
    waitingForInput = true;
    appendInput(s + ": ");
    input.requestFocus();
    String result = "";
    synchronized (holder) {

        worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String doInBackground() {
                while (holder.isEmpty()) {
                    //System.out.println("input inside 2"); //STOPS HERE
                    try {
                        holder.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return holder.remove(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void done() {
                String s ="";
                try {
                    s = super.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(s);

            }
        };

        while(!worker.isDone()) {}
        try {
            result = worker.get().toString();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Where is this "hierarchy" called from: `InputThread widthThread = new InputThread("width", console_instance);`?

Comment: @markspace Second from last code block

Comment: @markspace oh, sorry I misread your question. That's where the hierarchy starts, but i'll post a longer one in a sec to show where this is being called from. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: My point is "which thread is waiting", because if it's the EDT that's the problem right there.

Comment: @markspace How would I be able to test that theory?

Comment: Well, what thread do you call `appendCommand` on?  It should be as simple as looking at your code.  If not, can print the value of `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` to verify.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread()

Comment: @markspace I just added that into the hierarchy

Comment: Well, yeah, you're blocking the EDT when you wait for `holder` to get filled.  You can't do that.

Comment: @markspace Can you give me an idea of how to not do this inorder to achieve the thread inside the `start(Level l)` method? How would I prevent this? Sorry, this is the first time that I am working with synchronize...

Comment: @markspace or should I create a new `Thread` inside the EDT?

Comment: Just don't call it from the EDT.  Can you call it from the main thread instead?  Or if not, use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to spawn a background thread.

Comment: @markspace I need to fire an event when enter is pressed and `waitingForInput` is `true`, so I need to call it inside the EDT. I'll attempt to create a `SwingWorker` thread inside the EDT. I'll report back with the results.

Comment: @markspace I have no idea what I'm doing... Could you please show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I could but it's going to take a while.  Not a simple problem here.  Might be later today.

Comment: @markspace ah, thanks alot :-)! I'll just experiment meanwhile...

Comment: @markspace Hi Mark, sorry if I am an inconvenience, but could you please help me with the problem? I have tried to solve it, to no avail... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by wrapping the original `Map` inside another `Map` which calls a method when the wrapped map's `put(...)` is called. This passes it to my other class `CommandHandler` and from there it's prety self explanotary.